# Running Map Reduce on a data set of around 10 GB on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-map-reduce

I want to store around 10 GB of data on AWS services and use map reduce to process the data. 
Is using EC2 the best option ? I want to use free tier service, it says maximum of 613 MB for free services on EC2 and that does not satisfy my requirement. I am doing a hobby project and my expenses are limited.
The free tier FAQ also talks about using AWS EBS with free 30 GB of data. Can I use  Map Reduce services on EBS too, since AFAIK EMR is only available on EC2 ?
Does anyone know of any other alternatives that I can use for the same ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the AWS Simply Monthly Calculator, located at http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html#s=EMR, to get a feel for how much your project will cost using AWS.

The recommended workflow for EMR is to store data in an S3 bucket. So in the calculator, click S3 on the left. In the form enter 10G. The price for S3 storage is about $0.10 per gb/mo, so 10G costs about $1.00/mo.

Then, click on Amazon Elastic Map Reduce on the left. The form allows you to select predicted number of instances, hours/week or hours/mo expected usage, and expected instance type needed for your project. For example, for a project that requires 20 hrs/week using 1 Small EC2 is estimated to cost around $6.00. Micro instances do not seem to be offered with EMR.

Therefore, if you think you can get by with a Small Instance, and you plan to use it infrequently, your expenses might be under $10 per mo.

To reduce expenses even further, you could use spot instances rather than standard instances, as explained here: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/#7.